# IP Address Command Line

Tags: command-line, ip

What is the command that shows your computer's personal IP address? I have tried

```
ip addr show
```

But that shows much more than I want to see.

Answer (score 0):

Press "CTRL+T" on your keyboard to open up the terminal.

Then type in `ifconfig`, press enter and your ip address will be shown as

`inet addr xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`.

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect answer, but I do

```
ifconfig | grep 'inet addr:' | sed 's/.\{40\}$//' | sed 's/inet addr://g' | tr -d '[:blank:]' | tr --delete '\n'
```